# NHibernate. Distinct parent child fetching

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I've got common NH mapping;

```
  <class name="Order, SummaryOrder.Core" table='order'>
      <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="int">
         <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
         <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
    <many-to-one name="Client" class="SummaryOrderClient, SummaryOrder.Core"      column="summary_order_client_id"
            cascade="none"/>
    <many-to-one name="Provider" class="SummaryOrderClient, SummaryOrder.Core" column="summary_order_provider_id"
           cascade="none"/>
    <set name="Items" cascade="all">
        <key column="order_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="OrderItem, Clients.Core" />
    </set>  
 </class>
```

Want get list by this criteria

```
ICriteria criteria = NHibernateStateLessSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order)); ;
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Or
                (Restrictions.Eq(String.Format("{0}.Id", SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order.Properties.Client), idClient),
                  Restrictions.Eq(String.Format("{0}.Id", SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order.Properties.Provider), idClient))).
                  SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).
                  SetFetchMode(SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order.Properties.Items, FetchMode.Join);
        return criteria.List<SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order>() as List<SummaryOrder.Core.Domains.Order>
```

But I've got duplicates.. When I execute One restriction (without OR) I got distinct collection of orders, but Restriction OR brakes my query. I wanna get distinct(at client yet) collection of orders. What's wrong. Please HELP!

This hql is working. Why couldn't I get this result by criteria API?

```
       select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.Items where o.Client.Id=1 or o.Provider.Id=1
```

Comment: what is your "idClient" in the example above? and also in the Restrictions.Or you are using idClient for Client and Provider properties, this is not a mistake is it?

Comment: idClient is id(int) of Client. No it's not error. I need this logic.

Answer (score 0):

check your mapping for Provider:

```
<many-to-one name="Provider" class="SummaryOrderClient, SummaryOrder.Core"     column="summary_order_provider_id"
           cascade="none"/>
```

the class name is wrong !?